# Wordpress how to use both index and home.php

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have both index.php and home.php template under themes

```
website/theme/mytheme/
-home.php
-index.php
-header.php
-footer.php
```

When home.php is present,my homepage will be home.php

1)My home.php is actually my home page, which includes a large picture and some description of my website.

2)index.php will be normal blog template, which includes all posts in the blog,header,footer,sidebar...

May i know how to make both index and home available?

-In my home page, when i click a link with url like"www.website.com/blog", it will prompt to index.php which show the blog(normal wordpress main page).

Answer (score 0):

In wordpress normally home.php is for blogpage and and index.php is for the main front page. Nowdays frontpage.php displays main page when website loads

you can change the frontpage display using setting->reading and front page to your index.php and post page as blog page or in your case home.php

Comment: if my home.php is blogpage, index.php /front-page is my main page, how to create a link(a href="" for home.php in main page)

Comment: is it able to make it like www.xxx.com/blog   for home.php ?